# Pull specific category in Magento and only return configurables

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to develop a module that only loops through one category and shows those products.  The following code does that, however it will pull the product for every size that is in that category.  Can someone help me modify it to only pull the configurables?  The code I am using is something like:

```
$my_category_id ="12";
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($my_category_id));
```

and the loop is like :

```
  <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

       <img class="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"  src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />

    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your project collection:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::CONFIGURABLE));
```

Comment: Also you can use constant `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::CONFIGURABLE` instead of hardcoded string. It will help to get rid of mistypos and then spending hours for finding it out, because invalid constant name will rise a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR when I try to use your code Chris and Ivan I dont understand how to use that constant

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$my_category_id ="12";
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','small_image','short_description'), 'inner')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',array('eq'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::CONFIGURABLE))
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($my_category_id));`